# How to import a config file into Vue.JS+Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm setting configs in my main.js file before calling Vue :

```
Vue.prototype.$api_url = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://api.xxx.com' : 'https://yyy.test:8443'
```

It works if I access `this.$api_url` in any Vue file.

But in store.js (Vuex), it's another Vue Instance that is rendered, so I can't access `this.$api_url`.

What about setting the configs in a file and `Vue.use(configs.js)` ?

What should I do inside the configs file in order to get its variables in `main.js/store.js` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make a standalone config.js file and export your config object from that file. And import config where ever you need config.
You can also assign the same config to Vue's prototype if you want that to be provided in all Vue components.

**Update:**

So here is how you can do this:

In your config.js

```
let config;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  config = {
    $api_url: "https://api.xxx.com",
    timeoutDuration: 30000,
    someOtherProps: 'xyz'
  };
} else {
  config = {
    $api_url: "https://yyy.test:8443",
    timeoutDuration: 1000,
    someOtherProps: 'abc'
  };
}

export { config }
```

In your main.js

```
import { config } from 'config';

Vue.prototype.appConfig = config
```

use `this.appConfig.$api_url` whatever way you want to use in .vue files

In your store.js

```
import { config } from 'config';
```

use `config.$api_url` whatever way you want to use

Comment: Thank you, could you provide an example ?
Here's what I tried to do :

`export function VueConfigs(){
    return {
        $api_url        : process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://api.xxx.com' : 'https://yyy.test:8443',

    }
}`

Comment: This is fine, but sometimes you don't want to be putting tokens and things in SCM.  Seems like we have a strategy where we use the `.env.development` or a `.env.development.local` (unsaved to git) and then Webpack is taking care of it.  But this assumes you are building and deploying to a specific lab and those values are present either SCM or apart of some search and replace with CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vite you can externalize a config file without a store with this:

### Create your config js module for instance in `config/settings.js`

```js
const config = {
    apiUrl:'https://yesno.wtf/api'
};

export { config }
```

### Mark the file as external in `vite.config.js`

```js
export default defineConfig({

.
.
.
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['/config/settings.js']
    }
  }
})
```

### Access the file in your `main.js` and store the settings globally

```js
import { config } from './config/settings.js'
app.config.globalProperties.config = config
```